# Cannot achieve desired output of do-while loop

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I want my code to list the calculation with an = followed by the final answer, but I'm not sure how to do that. The way my code is written right now, the output prints an extra plus sign between the final iteration and the equal sign. Below is the body for the code, any help is appreciated.

```
int main()
{
double fraction = 0.0, numerator = 0.0, n, denominator = 0.0;

    do
    {
        numerator = numerator + 1;
        denominator = n;
        --n;
        fraction = fraction + (numerator / denominator);
        cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << " + ";
    }

    while (denominator > 1); 

    cout << " = " << fraction << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change this line

```
cout << numerator << "/" << denominator << " + ";
```

to

```
cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
if (denominator > 1) {
  cout << " + ";
}
```

This makes sure you don't print the + at the very last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically just printing the `+` as a separator between items in a list. For cases like this, you typically want to do one of two things:

1. Figure out if this is the first iteration. If it's not, print the separator before the item.
2. Figure out if it's the last iteration. If it's not, print the separator after the item.

Choosing between these is pretty much up to you. I tend to prefer the former, but some people prefer the latter, and (even though they're obviously wrong) it's a perfectly reasonable choice.